# How to make knockout with nested object which might not be array always

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I had a nested JSON object in this form

```
var termValues=[
    {
   clause_title:"One",
   clause_id:"One",
CM_terms: [
            { termName: 'CompanyName', type:"text", termValue:"CompanyName1", termId:'1' },
            { termName: 'Contract termValue', type:"number", termValue:"1234",termId:'2' },
            { termName: 'Contract End', type:"date", termValue:"2012-02-02", termId:'3'  }
          ]
    },
    {
    clause_title:"Two",
    clause_id:"Two",
CM_terms: [
            { termName: 'CompanyName', type:"text", termValue:"CompanyName2", termId:'4' },
            { termName: 'Contract termValue', type:"number", termValue:"5678",termId:'5' },
            { termName: 'Contract End', type:"date", termValue:"2011-02-02", termId:'6'  }
          ]


    }
];
```

I applied binding in this form

```
function TestModel (termValues)
{
var self=this;
self.Clauses=ko.observableArray(termValues)
}
ko.applyBindings(new TestModel(termValues),$("#ctrTerms1")[0]);
```

HTML code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Clauses" id="ctrTerms1">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="control-bar panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title" style="overflow:auto">
                <a class="col-md-12 clref">
                    <span class="clause-title" title="Click to edit" data-bind="text: Clauses.clause_title"></span>
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" data-bind="foreach: CM_terms">
                <div class="form-group"  >
                    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" data-bind="text: termName">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control cttermValue" id="clauseTitle" data-bind="value: termValue">
                    </div>

                 </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now the issue is if I have more than 1 term I CM_terms will be in the form of an Array so for-each of CM_terms will work, But if I have only 1 CM_terms (Single object), Knock out is not able to bind as CM_term will not be array.

```
var termValues=[
    {
   clause_title:"One",
   clause_id:"One",
CM_terms: 
            { termName: 'CompanyName', type:"text", termValue:"companyName1", termId:'1' }
];
```

How Can I make 'CM_term' values to convert to Array if it is a Single Object. 
As of now I am Iterating termValues and making CM_terms to Array if its not an Array and then applying Bindings.

Is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have single object then push it into array. In your case CM_terms always should be an array, no matter whether it has single object or multiple objects.

```
var termValues=[
{
    clause_title: "One",
    clause_id: "One",
    CM_terms: [
        {
            termName: 'CompanyName',
            type: "text",
            termValue: "Cordys",
            termId: '1'
        }
    ]
];
```

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/NX4LP/)

Comment: Thank You, But As mentioned in the last statement of my question, I said that I have implemented the your suggestion. Is there any other Other way for ex: using some knockout features

Comment: This way or other way you have to make CM_terms as an array. You can use knockout plugin or jquery map to avoid manual iteration.

Comment: Hi can you add the code of jquery map and knockout plugin for this. I am not aware of these

Comment: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/ take help from these links. it would be better if you try it youself.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can solve the problem. Got a clue from one of the stack-over flow post(will post if found gain)

We can use data-bind="foreach:{data:$data.CM_Terms}". We get desired result even if CM_Terms is not an Array

```
<div class="panel-body" data-bind="foreach: {data:$data.CM_terms}">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cn2Y/)